# How to deal with `__int128` in gdb?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I am currently struggling with gdb to deal with gcc-specific type `__int128` within gdb. I manage to do a few on-the-fly computation such as:

```
(gdb) p /x (__int128) (1 << (8 * 8))
$1 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000001
(gdb) ptype bitmask
type = const __int128 unsigned
```

But, each time I get a bit more complex in the expression I try to evaluate, I get:

```
(gdb) p /x ((((__int128) 1) << (8 * 8)) - 1)
That operation is not available on integers of more than 8 bytes.
(gdb) p /x (__int128) 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffff
Numeric constant too large.
```

So, is there a way to evaluate such expression on `__int128` within gdb?

Comment: your first computation is wrong because `1 << (8 * 8)` has type `int` **and** therefore the behaviour of that expression is *undefined*

Comment: In fact, I wrote this expression because it was one that was giving some answer... But, I do not really care about it, what I am looking for is always giving the last error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to print a constant value, the `py print(expr128)` idea works fantastically due to Python's arbitrary integer precision.

If, however, you need to work with an actual C variable of type `__int128`, you'll need to convert it temporarily into something like `unsigned long long[2]` to perform operations on it in GDB, but remember that you're then working with an array of 2 64-bit values, so `X[0] << 64` will not work as it would with the true 128-bit `__int128` type.  GDB can print the value; it just can't manipulate its bits.  GCC allows you to manipulate its bits; your libc just can't print the value using `printf` and there might not even be any GCC-specific code that allows it to do so.

Here's a sample shell session showing how troublesome this compiler-specific type is to work with in GDB:

```
$ nl bar.c
    1   int main(void)
    2   {
    3       __int128 v = 1;
    4       v <<= 62;
    5       v <<= 2;
    6   }
$ gcc -g -o bar bar.c
$ gdb -q ./bar
Reading symbols from ./bar...done.
(gdb) break 5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5e8: file bar.c, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/luser/bar

Breakpoint 1, main () at bar.c:5
5       v <<= 2;
(gdb) print/x *(long long(*)[2])&v
$1 = {0x4000000000000000, 0x0}
(gdb) print/x (*(long long(*)[2])&v)[0]+1
$2 = {0x4000000000000001, 0x0}
(gdb) next
6   }
(gdb) print/x *(long long(*)[2])&v
$3 = {0x0, 0x1}
(gdb) print/x (*(long long(*)[2])&v)[0]+1
$4 = {0x1, 0x1}
```

Taking into account my machine's little endian CPU, the results are (sort of) clear:

```
$1 = 0x0000 0000 0000 0000
       4000 0000 0000 0000  # 1<<62
$2 = 0x0000 0000 0000 0000
       4000 0000 0000 0001  #(1<<62) + 1
$3 = 0x0000 0000 0000 0001
       0000 0000 0000 0000  # 1<<64
$4 = 0x0000 0000 0000 0001
       0000 0000 0000 0001  #(1<<64) + 1
```

With values this large, even hexadecimal is getting to be a bit cumbersome, but you get the idea: working with these values in GDB might be a problem with all of the parentheses you need to deal with, plus you need to keep your target machine's endianness in mind when manipulating the value as well as tracking overflow.

My suggestion: link in some arithmetic routines that work with `__int128` values to aid debugging, so you can use things like `call negate128 (value)` in GDB to obtain the result of the C expression `-value` where `value` has type `__int128`.  No need for overflow checks either since the machine will handle that for you as it would with any other type, so go ahead and write things like this (assuming you're working with a system where overflow doesn't kill your program or the entire machine):

```cpp
__int128 add128(__int128 a, __int128 b) { return a + b; }
__int128 sub128(__int128 a, __int128 b) { return a - b; }
__int128 shl128(__int128 a, int n) { return a << n; }
__int128 shr128(__int128 a, int n) { return a >> n; }
```

Answer (score 2):

> So, is there a way to evaluate such expression on 128 within gdb

Not directly, but you could use built-in python (with its unlimited precision) to achieve somewhat equivalent result:

```
(gdb) py print('0x%x' % ((1 << (8 * 8)) - 1))
0xffffffffffffffff

(gdb) py print('0x%x' % ((1 << (8 * 8 + 5)) + 1))
0x200000000000000001
```